# Unable to Edit template any object In visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015

Unable to Edit template any object In visual studio 2015. I try with blend But I can't do that.
please help me? If you don't know, please make a edit template for Button and post it here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve question completely But I found something useful for default template of controls in Windows 8.1.
[Windows 8.1 default XAML templates and styles](https://gist.github.com/longzheng/2308859)